# Discord.py - How to set slash command parameter's name and description

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm trying to make discord bot using python discord.py module, and I wanna add slash command with member parameter using CommandTree.

I added parameter but it does not have it's own parameter name(displays as it's variable name) and description.
How can I add its name and description?

```
@tree.command(name="send", description="this command sends money to target", guild=discord.Object(guildId))
async def send(interaction, member: discord.Member): # "member" parameter should have description
    # sends money to member
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `app_commands.describe` and the `app_commands.rename` decorators to do this:

Example:

```py
from discord import app_commands

@tree.command(name="send", description="this command sends money to target", guild=discord.Object(guildId))
@app_commands.describe(member="The member to send the money to")
@app_commands.rename(member='whatever_you_want')
async def send(interaction, member: discord.Member):
    # sends money to member
```

For the description, you could also use docstrings to accomplish your goal:

```
@tree.command(name="send", guild=discord.Object(guildId))
async def send(interaction, member: discord.Member):
    """This command sends money to a target.

    Parameters
    -----------
    member: discord.Member
        The member to send the money to
    """
```

discord.py will parse them automatically for you, if you use one of the supported styles.

Docs:

https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/interactions/api.html?highlight=describe#discord.app_commands.describe

https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactions/api.html#discord.app_commands.rename

Answer (score -1):

You should add the `help` parameter to specify the name and description, like this:

```py
@tree.command(name="send", description="this command sends money to target", guild=discord.Object(guildId))
async def send(interaction, member: discord.Member, help="The member to send money to"):
    # ...
```